# Laravel mix undefined error

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I try to minify my sources with laravel mix and here is my `webpack.mix.js` file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.styles([
  'theme/admin/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/zabuto_calendar.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/lineicons/style.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/style.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/style-responsive.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/chart-master/Chart.js'
], 'public/css/admin.css');

mix.js([
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.sparkline.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/common-scripts.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/gritter-conf.js'
], 'public/js/admin.js');
```

If i only use styles part on `npm run watch` it return success the problem is in js files and specifically in this part `'theme/admin/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',`

[image]

any idea?

Comment: Verify if your bootstrap version is compatible with jquery Version!

Comment: @HorecioDias I downloaded again bootstrap 3 jquery, js and css files edited all my webpack file still same error.

Comment: @mafortis Why would you use two versions of `jQuery` `'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.js'` and , `'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'` ?